# How to move files from folder to another using the paths listed in a ListBox

Tags: vb.net

I have a list box that has paths to files. How can I move the selected file items that have the paths to another folder?

Comment: This is not a question. As far as I can tell you haven't asked one. Please take the [tour], read through the [help] and [ask] to learn how to ask a better question. Also, it's not really clear why antivirus is tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each SelectedItem In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        Try
            File.Move(SelectedItem.ToString(), "New path here")
        Catch : End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

And with error handling, so if a file is not accessible it will continue to the next one.

**Hope that helped you :)**